# Norm of a generalized Hilbert matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-norms, hilbert-matrices

Given positive numbers $a_1,\ldots, a_m, b_1,\ldots, b_n$, define a $m\times n$ matrix

$X_{ij}=(a_i-b_j)/(a_i+b_j)$.

It is a bit similar to the Hilbert matrix.

The question is whether its spectral norm can be upper bounded by some absolute constant?

Comment: I suppose "spectral norm" refers to the induced $2$-norm (the largest singular value). If you mean a constant that depends on $m$ and $n$, the answer is "yes", because your $X$ lies inside the compact set of all matrices elementwise bounded by $\pm1$. If you mean a constant that does not depend on $m$ and $n$, the answer is "no". With $a_1=1$ and all other $a_i$s and $b_j$s equal to some sufficiently small $c>0$, $\|X\|$ can be made arbitrarily close to $n$.